# How to conditionally include a file into Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

Consider the following Makefile:

```
# <include global configuration Makefile>

INCL = -I../include \
       -I<whatever>

CPPFLAGS=$(DEFS) $(INCL)
CXXFLAGS = -O0 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0

SRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp)

OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

all: $(OBJS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<


depend: .depend

.depend: $(SRCS) 
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -M $^ > $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)
    rm .depend


-include .depend
```

This Makefile creates an `#include` dependency chain using the `g++ -M` command, and includes it. This can be a rather long process. The problem is that this file is generated even if `make clean` is called, when this file would be deleted anyway. Is ther a way to conditionally include this file, and not bother creating it if the clean target is run?

Comment: This is answered in detail [here][1].

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714041/why-does-this-makefile-execute-a-target-on-make-clean/3714054#3714054

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this:

```
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
-include .depend
endif
```

See the [make manual page on Goals](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/make/Goals.html) for more information

Edit: `-include` cannot be tab indented, otherwise it is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You can do such dependencies for *free* (i.e., at no runtime cost) during the compile. When you run `clean`, the dependencies are naturally not remade. See the section *Combining Compilation and Dependency Generation* in Paul Smith's [Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation](http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html) paper.